# Is there a way to conditionally alter the size of text in a Tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I am creating an application which displays song lyrics for entered songs, however, longer songs do not fit, so I want to shrink the size of the text if it is a longer song. I am unsure about how to go about this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried using a conditional, however, it did not seem to work.

```
file = open(artist + song + ".txt", "r")
lyrics = file.read()
lines = file.readlines()
lyricsLabel = tk.Label(root, text = lyrics)

lyricsLabel.config(font = ("TkDefaultFont", 5))

lyricsLabel.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

if playSong == True:
    os.startfile(artist + song + ".mp3")
```

Comment: What about placing the text in a widget that can scroll? Seems easier to me.

Comment: *"tried conditional, did not seem to work."*: Didn't see the condition, [edit] your Question and show your attemp.

Answer (score 0):

you could measure the length of the text file by using `len()` , then break to elif statements that modify the font size. e.g.

```
text = len(song)

if text < 20:
   font_size = 20
elif text > 20 and < 40:
   font_size = 15
```

etc...

then

```
song = Lable(root, text= song)
song.config(font = ("TkDefaultFont", font_size))
```